# How to implement function InitInstance() for class Derived from CDialog? MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I have a class:

```
include<afxwin.h>
include<Winuser.h>
include<Windows.h>


HWND hwndOwner;

class CChildView :public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CChildView)

public:

CChildView();
~CChildView();
afx_msg void OnPaint();
afx_msg void OnLevelProf();
afx_msg void OnLevelAmat();
afx_msg void OnLevelBeg();
afx_msg void OnStepC();
void new_game();

virtual BOOL InitInstance();
//void CloseWindow();
BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
int end_analyze();
void ii();
unsigned long calculate(int id, int x, int y);
afx_msg void OnNewGame();
//void Invalidate();
afx_msg void OnX1010();
afx_msg void OnX1919();
afx_msg void OnX3030();
afx_msg void OnX5050();
afx_msg void OnX100100();
//MessageBoxW();
void resize_window();
afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT, CPoint xy);
//void GetWindowRect(RECT);
//int MessageBoxW();
 void OnStepH();
void set_chеcked_menu(unsigned int old_id, unsigned int new_id);
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

};

How should I to implement the method InitInstance to my app not to Catch a NUllReferenceExeption in AfxWinMAin()? That what i have now:

```
CChildView obj;

BOOL CChildView::InitInstance()
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    obj.Create(L"dsa", nullptr);

    return FALSE;
}
```

I made an oj in order to this

> [How to get rid of null reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2009/06/21/why-afxgetthread-returns-null-in-afxwinmain.aspx)

Comment: Side Note: INIT'COMMON'CONTROL'SEX (sorry)

Comment: Likely `INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls = {}` (Initialize with zeros, but it's a shot into the blue)

Comment: I'm confused at what you're trying to do.  InitInstance is a child method of CWinApp, **not**, CDialog.

Comment: @rrirower: `InitInstance` is a member of [CWinThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5k7zxtw.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the wrong question. You are required to implement InitInstance as a member of your CWinApp class (or CWinAppEx). See my answer to your previous question for an easy way to create a dialog-based MFC application that will build and run first try.